# using jq to break array of elements into multiple arrays of varying length

Tags: javascript, arrays, jq

I have a JSON object that I'd like to transform using jq from one form to another (of course, I could use javascript or python and iterate, but jq would be preferable). The issue is that the input contains long arrays that needs to be broken into multiple smaller arrays whenever data stops repeating within the first array. I'm not really sure how to describe this problem so I'll just put an example out here which is hopefully more explanatory. The one safe assumption-- if it is of any help-- is that the input data is always pre-sorted on the first two elements (e.g. "row_x" and "col_y"):

input:

```
{
  "headers": [ "col1", "col2", "col3" ],
  "data": [
    [ "row1","col1","b","src2" ],
    [ "row1","col1","b","src1" ],
    [ "row1","col1","b","src3" ],
    [ "row1","col2","d","src4" ],
    [ "row1","col2","e","src5" ],
    [ "row1","col2","f","src6" ],
    [ "row1","col3","j","src7" ],
    [ "row1","col3","g","src8" ],
    [ "row1","col3","h","src9" ],
    [ "row1","col3","i","src10" ],
    [ "row2","col1","l","src13" ],
    [ "row2","col1","j","src11" ],
    [ "row2","col1","k","src12" ],
    [ "row2","col3","o","src15" ]
  ]
}
```

desired output:

```
{
  "headers": [ "col1", "col2", "col3" ],
  "values": [
    [["b","b","b"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i","j"]],
    [["j","k","l"],null,["o"]]
  ],
  "sources": [
    [["src1","src2","src3"],["src4","src5","src6"],["src7","src8","src9","src10"]],
    [["src11","src12","src13"],null,["src15"]]
  ]
}
```

Is this doable at all in jq?

UPDATE: a variant of this is to retain the original data order, so the output is as follows:

```
{
  "headers": [ "col1", "col2", "col3" ],
  "values": [
    [["b","b","b"],["d","e","f"],["j","g","h","i"]],
    [["l","j","k"],null,["o"]]
  ],
  "sources": [
    [["src2","src1","src3"],["src4","src5","src6"],["src7","src8","src9","src10"]],
    [["src13","src11","src12"],null,["src15"]]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it doable? Of course!

First you'll want to group the data by rows then columns.  Then with the groups, build your values/sources arrays.

```
.headers as $headers | .data
    # make the data easier to access
    | map({ row: .[0], col: .[1], val: .[2], src: .[3] })
    # keep it sorted so they are in expected order in the end
    | sort_by([.row,.col,.src])
    # group by rows
    | group_by(.row)
    # create a map to each of the cols for easier access
    | map(group_by(.col)
        | reduce .[] as $col ({};
            .[$col[0].col] = [$col[] | {val,src}]
        )
    )
    # build the result
    | {
        headers: $headers,
        values: map([.[$headers[]] | [.[]?.val]]),
        sources: map([.[$headers[]] | [.[]?.src]])
    }
```

This will produce the following result:

```
{
  "headers": [ "col1", "col2", "col3" ],
  "values": [
    [
      [ "b", "b", "b" ],
      [ "d", "e", "f" ],
      [ "i", "j", "g", "h" ]
    ],
    [
      [ "j", "k", "l" ],
      [],
      [ "o" ]
    ]
  ],
  "sources": [
    [
      [ "src1", "src2", "src3" ],
      [ "src4", "src5", "src6" ],
      [ "src10", "src7", "src8", "src9" ]
    ],
    [
      [ "src11", "src12", "src13" ],
      [],
      [ "src15" ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Jeff - @mwag wants 'null' values in the (implicit) matrix.

Comment: is there any way to modify this to retain the original order of the data (which I know is not what the original question asked)? I tried removing the ```| sort_by([.row,.col,.src])``` line but it does not always retain the exact original data order

Comment: Removing the sort line should do it. I only added that in since your example seemed to have the results reordered. What does your data look like that's giving you the unexpected ordering? The way this is written, the relative ordering within the data list should be in-tact.

Comment: it'll sort on value instead. so using the same input, removing the sort line will result in the 'src8' and related data coming before the 'src7' and related data, which is not the order it came in. I tried adding a running number (like a row number) to the beginning of each input data line, and using that to sort, but still wasn't able to get it to work...

Comment: getting closer: if I modify the input so that each row begins with a running counter (e.g, ```[1, "row1"..],[2, "row1"..]```, then I can modify your ```reduce``` clause to be ```reduce (.[] | sort_by(.ind)) as $col``` and it will retain the original order...

Answer (score 0):

Since the primary data source here can be thought of as a
two-dimensional matrix, it may be worth considering a
matrix-oriented approach to the problem, especially if it is
intended that empty rows in the input matrix are not simply omitted, or if
the number of columns in the matrix is not initially known.

To spice things up a little, let's choose to represent an m x n
matrix, M, as a JSON array of the form [m, n, a] where a is an array
of arrays, such that a[i][j] is the element of M in row i, column j.

First, let's define some basic matrix-oriented operations:

```
def ij(i;j): .[2][i][j];

def set_ij(i;j;value):
  def max(a;b): if a < b then b else a end;
  .[0] as $m | .[1] as $n
  | [max(i+1;$m), max(j+1;$n), (.[2] | setpath([i,j];value)) ];
```

The data source uses strings of the form "rowI" for row i
and "colJ" for row j, so we define a matrix-update function accordingly:

```
def update_row_col( row; col; value):
  ((row|sub("^row";"")|tonumber) - 1) as $r
   | ((col|sub("^col";"")|tonumber) - 1) as $c
   | ij($r;$c) as $v
   | set_ij($r; $c; if $v == null then [value] else $v + [value] end) ;
```

Given an array of items of the form ["rowI","colJ", V, S],
generate a matrix with the value {"source": S, "value": V} at row I
and column J:

```
def generate:
  reduce .[] as $x ([0,0,null];
    update_row_col( $x[0];  $x[1]; { "source": $x[3], "value": $x[2] }) );
```

Now we turn to the desired output.  The following filter will extract f from the input matrix, producing an array of arrays, replacing [] with null:

```
def extract(f):
  . as $m
  | (reduce range(0; $m[0]) as $i
      ([];
       . + ( reduce range(0; $m[1]) as $j
            ([];
         . + [ $m | ij($i;$j) // [] | map(f) ]) ) ))
  | map( if length == 0 then null else . end );
```

Putting it all together (generating the headers dynamically is left as an exercise for the interested reader):

```
{headers} +
  (.data | generate
   | { "values": extract(.value), "sources": extract(.source) } )
```

Output:

```json
{
  "headers": [
    "col1",
    "col2",
    "col3"
  ],
  "values": [
    [
      "b",
      "b",
      "b"
    ],
    [
      "d",
      "e",
      "f"
    ],
    [
      "j",
      "g",
      "h",
      "i"
    ],
    [
      "l",
      "j",
      "k"
    ],
    null,
    [
      "o"
    ]
  ],
  "sources": [
    [
      "src2",
      "src1",
      "src3"
    ],
    [
      "src4",
      "src5",
      "src6"
    ],
    [
      "src7",
      "src8",
      "src9",
      "src10"
    ],
    [
      "src13",
      "src11",
      "src12"
    ],
    null,
    [
      "src15"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: one of the problems I have with this solution is that although it works for the specific sample input provided, it does so by making the assumption, which is not provided in the question, that the input will always be of the literal form "row1"... and "col1" ..., rather than being any arbitrary string. for my actual use case with "real-world" data, this assumption cannot be guaranteed, so this solution doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses **reduce**, **getpath** and **setpath**

```
  .headers as $headers
| reduce .data[] as [$r,$c,$v,$s] (
    {headers:$headers, values:{}, sources:{}}
  ; setpath(["values",  $r, $c]; (getpath(["values", $r, $c])  // []) + [$v])
  | setpath(["sources", $r, $c]; (getpath(["sources", $r, $c]) // []) + [$s])
  )
| .values  = [ .values[]  | [ .[ $headers[] ] ] ]
| .sources = [ .sources[] | [ .[ $headers[] ] ] ]
```

Sample output (manually reformatted for readability)

```
{
 "headers":["col1","col2","col3"],
 "values":[[["b","b","b"],["d","e","f"],["j","g","h","i"]],
           [["l","j","k"],null,["o"]]],
 "sources":[[["src2","src1","src3"],["src4","src5","src6"],["src7","src8","src9","src10"]],
            [["src13","src11","src12"],null,["src15"]]]
}
```